# Requesting answer or solution from a particular SO user

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'm looking the way to refer a question to a specific Stack Overflow user which I know is an expert on the subject, so I will be able to get his attention onto the problem and will get the best possible solution quickly.

Additionally, we are already provided with a feature to share a link to question via:

- Email
- Google+
- Twitter
- Facebook

So why not within **SO** as well?

Request to provide this feature. It will greatly help users to get precise solutions to their critical problems more quickly.

Answer (score 25):

If the user is known to frequent chat, you can *politely* show them a link to your question and ask if they've got any insights - just take care to not be a pest about it. Badgering another user in chat to answer one of your questions will likely get you suspended in chat.

The other thing you can do is offer a bounty and hope they decide to engage, but if they don't - they don't.

We don't facilitate any means of privately contacting another user, so if your first few attempts to attract their attention aren't successful - don't keep trying. It's very likely that someone else can give you a great answer, perhaps the same one that the user you had in mind might have offered.

Comment: a bounty can be offer after 2 days of posting only. and also it is a feature request instead.

Comment: "How can I achieve that?" is not a feature request. And besides, he's already said no, "We don't facilitate any means of privately contacting another user"

Comment: @Ahsan Shah: Because it says that your email is never displayed (to anyone except yourself).

Comment: Private, personal, whatever you want to call it, it's the same thing. There are no other supported ways of contacting someone other than what is given to you publicly, either by the site or the user's profile, and you should not use comments for anything other than to supplement the question/answer at hand.

Comment: If you're *only* ever going to talk to someone just because you think it'll get you "perfect possible solution more quickly", you'll find out even more quickly that not everyone is receptive to that idea.

Comment: The last thing we need are notable experts in their fields not using SO any more because the clueless masses keep pinging them for help with basic problems...

Comment: Could that be that a silver badge on an argument can be prioritized to golden badges?