# Asking for help from specific users

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, comment-replies, private-messaging

I have a situation: I found the answer to my question (the similar question was asked before and someone gave answer to it), but I have additional questions regarding the given answer.

I cannot post in comments to that answer (50 rep barrier), and I cannot find any way to send a message to the user who gave an answer.

So, what are my options? Ask the same question again? Don't think it's OK.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Requesting answer or solution from a particular SO user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251435), note the 'status declined' on that.

Comment: Also read [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) as it will improve the quality of your questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a new question explaining clearly (best with your attempts and code samples) what you have trouble with. You can give links to the posts you mention to give context. Please remember to follow guidelines from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on asking questions. For example, in this case (because you've mentioned you have "questions") focus on one issue per one post.

Asking for help from specific users is not the way things work here, and is discouraged. After you've gained some rep it would be possible, for some users, to find them in a chatroom - however often this is also frowned upon (depends on the user/context though, sometimes it's all right).