# (How) Should I flag comment "Please look at my question"

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Under my (2012) question [Why does CreateProcess give error 193 (%1 is not a valid Win32 app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637203/why-does-createprocess-give-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-app) a user [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637203/why-does-createprocess-give-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-app?noredirect=1#comment65828714_12637203)

> any idea about stackoverflow.com/questions/39245238/

pointing to a recent question he just posted.

I feel these kind of comments are not appropriate:

- it's a *forward* reference to a newer question not adding anything
- it's just poking me asking for help

How to act? I started flagging for moderator attention, but let's check here first what others think.

- Leave as is
- Flag as *not constructive*?
- Custom flag because of the forward reference?
- Custom flag because I don't want to be poked like this?
- Leave comment to that user?
- Other...

Comment: I usually ignore it unless the answer is really interesting

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

This use case clearly doesn't comply to these rules, so you should flag it. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/295232) suggests *not constructive* and *chatty* as appropriate flag options.

The only viable way of attraction attention of a user (unless it is a discussion about the current question/answer) is to [invite him/her to chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297564/4751173).

Answer (score 29):

Flag the comment; whatever reason you use doesn't matter too much. People have no business spamming unwanted links to their questions in comments on unrelated answers.

If there is a discussion between the answerer and the asker leading to them posting that link as a follow-up (often by the answerer's request), you can either leave it alone if in doubt, or if the entire discussion appears to be obsolete you can flag each of the comments, or custom-flag the entire answer, and let a moderator handle it. If they're clearly just spamming to get someone to look at their question there's no reason the comment should stick around and be an eyesore.

If you notice a user with a habit of doing this, feel free to point it out in a custom flag. A moderator will likely warn the user about this behavior as it's not welcome.

Comment: OK, I'll flag these as *not constructive*, they don't add anything to the question. (And that prevents a moderator flag). BTW It's no longer necessary in this case, the comment was removed (by ???)

Comment: Yup, also flagged

Comment: Of course it doesn't help when experienced users actively encourage this behavior.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825831/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-xslt/34552872#comment63725123_34552872

Comment: @Flynn1179: If they're soliciting a follow-up from the asker, let them have it. That said, there *are* some people out there who will take this to mean "it's OK for me to do this to *anyone* regardless of whether or not they asked for it", and of course also the people who are too desperate to care.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the discussion followup link to a new question. There have been numerous times that people ask me clarification questions for which I either don't know the answer or an answer would require more work than I want to do. I tell them to make a new question and then add a link to it in the comments. In this situation I feel that the link is both helpful and appropriate.

Answer (score -33):

As it's the only way to call a concrete user, it would be nice if you answer him under his question. Then he deletes his comment himself. Or you can answer under his comment, but then you have to delete your comment after he reads it.

There are no reasons for flagging until it's clear, he isn't going to remove his comment.

By the way, depending on relevancy of his question, maybe it's OK to leave it there.

Of course if someone spams many users with such comments, it definitely should be flagged.

Comment: It would be nice if the person did not post such a comment, they are unwanted.

Comment: @Stijn, there is meta or faq post where specified that if you need to ask concrete user, it's ok to post a comment under any his post, and remove it later.

Comment: Can you link the post in question? I'm pretty sure, if it exists, that it'll say not to use the 'feature' for this kind of thing. I certainly wouldn't appreciate it.

Comment: Me neither. Repeated requests for features to message a specific user (see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297562/3001761) have been rejected for this reason.

Comment: @Stijn, couldn't find it... But defenetely I saw it somewhere. And I didn't check concrete situation, my answer is for general situation.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266265/1288408

Comment: No, answering the begging promotes the abominable behaviour

Comment: @Qwertiy it's a bad answer for the generic or specific case. Answering is only going to encourage the commenter to hassle other users they think could help them. There aren't other ways *"to call concrete user"* because **the people on the receiving end don't want them**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it's not the thing that always should be used. But if someone once an year will ask one other guy to help him, because he knows that he can help - why not? If someone uses it for every his question - flag it. If you see it once and there were reasons to ask you - just answer.

Comment: Annoying behavior doesn't become OK just because it isn't frequent. And, as others have already stated, answering would just encourage people to do it more.

Comment: The only reason to post on unrelated question I can think of is to let user know that they could have done something better than deleting they other post/comment/edit... Begging for attention is not helping the user at all.

Comment: There are valid reasons for leaving a comment under a random answer to get in touch with them, e.g. to encourage them to undelete an answer that you thought would be useful with some improvement.  Begging for an answer is not one of the valid reasons.  I have once posted a comment asking a someone to look at something, but that was asking someone to clear up one thing that was part of a larger *answer* I'd written.  The answer I commented on was one on a related topic, by a user I've had comment discussions with before, so I'm hopeful it was well-received.  Very different from this case.